# Random HTML Code generated by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a simple question. I have this code for my audio player:

```
<audio class="audio-element" controls="true" preload="none">
  <source src="mp3file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /><br>
  <b>Your outdated browser does not support HTML5. <br>
     Get Mozilla Firefox <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/new/"> >HERE< </a>
  </b>
</audio>
```

is it possible to randomly generate the source src using Javascript?

Comment: ...what? I don't even...
Joking aside, your question is not clear at all, what is your goal? What is your problem? How can we help? Please edit your question and provide some clarifications.

Comment: sure why not, but if the "random" source is not a valid source why would you want to? Please explain the the reasoning behind why would would want to generate a random source.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question, right now the answer can be as simple as "yes"

Comment: Doesn't the brand new Firefox have a playlist and random-play button properties in audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by random source? If you generate a random string for your source it probably wouldn't be valid. What I think you want is to have an array of valid sources and select one of those valid sources at random.

In which case you would do this:

**HTML**

```
<audio class="audio-element" controls="true" preload="none" id='audio'>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Math.randInt = function(min, max){
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*((max+1)-min))+min);
};
var sources = [
    "source1.mp3",
    "source2.mp3",
    "source3.mp3"
];
document.getElementById("audio").src = sources[Math.randInt(0, sources.length-1)];
```

This will pick a random source from an array of valid sources which I think is what you want. But if you want to generate a "random source" you can do something stupid like this:

**HTML**

```
<audio class="audio-element" controls="true" preload="none" id='audio'>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Math.randInt = function(min, max){
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*((max+1)-min))+min);
};
document.getElementById("audio").src = Math.randInt(999999999,9999999999).toString(36);+".mp3";
```

That will generate a random string of numbers and letters as your source. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is super confusing, but you can create elements like this

```
var source = document.createElement('source');
```

and give it an `src` attribute like

```
source.src = 'myaudio.mp3';
```

Comment: @Nepoxx For simple/short code loading jQuery is overkill.

Comment: @Nepoxx how so? I completely disagree. Sure you can make a shorter snippet with less characters, chain calls and such, but, this is a one line command to create an element in pure JS. jQuery also could be doing many things in the background that you don't know. As user said above, it's hella overkill. I am a jQuery hater though... :)

Comment: jQuery **would** be overkill for the answer, but it might be useful for the user's purposes since I think the user isn't very familiar with those operations and jQuery abstracts them (for better or for worse, that's not the point).

Comment: @ShanRobertson After developing a large application that should support different types of clients one will love jQuery or any other stable DOM manipulation library :)

Comment: that couldn't be further from the truth for me. After starting on jQuery I started to make the move over to vanilla JS and frameworks like angular etc. I wrote a small library that deals with class manipulation and that was enough to replace jquery for me

Comment: Well, I started by learning JavaScript ages ago and I have written a small library (which I use for application that I develop) that does more than class manipulation, but the process of creating/maintaining a library that does all the basic tasks and is stable is very time-consuming. After all it's called "reinventing the wheel".

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element and apply random attributes to it - in this case, assigning a random audio file to `src`. The basic technique could be:

```
var audioFiles = [ 'music1.mp3', 'music2.mp3', 'music3.mp3' ]; 
// The above array would be populated from an AJAX call to the server to get
// the filenames, or however you get getting the filenames already 
var audio = document.getElementById('audio'); // or whatever ID you assign
var source = document.createElement('source'); 
var source.src = audioFiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * audioFiles.length)];
audio.appendChild(source);
```